# Strange behaviour of os.walk()

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, directory

I have been using `os.walk()` to traverse a bunch of subdirectories inside a directory `dir`. These subdirectories are numbered from 0001 to 0899. I assumed that `os.walk(dir)` traverses these subdirectories in numerical order, i.e., as they are shown in the finder (I am on Mac), and so far I have had no reason to believe that this is not true.

However, a few days ago I noticed something strange: `os.walk()` suddenly (?) traverses the folders non-numerically (but always in the same sequence, I think). I am fairly sure that this was not the case before - I would have noticed.

I am aware that I can use `sorted(os.walk(dir))` to have the subdirectories processed numerically, but that does not answer my question. How is it possible that the behaviour of `os.walk()` changed? Could it have to do with upgrading Python in the meantime (which I don't think I did - can this be checked somehow)?

EDIT: it occurred to my that I updated from OS Sierra to OS Sierra High in the meantime. Maybe that is where the answer lies?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question: it turns out that it was the fact that I had moved `dir` and its complete contents to a different place on my disk, thus giving them different addresses, that caused the different sorting.